# 4 > + 4 I would like to know what the plus stands for?

Tags: python

Ok, I get that four is not greater than four but what is confusing me is the + what does that mean? Why doesn't it cause an error? I know its false but whats up with the +?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **NO ERROR** in syntax.

`+4` signifies that 4 is positive. If you put `-4` it is negative 4 and you will get True.

Comment: Ooo ok, that makes sense thank you.I'm new to programming, and I thought it meant something else than positive maybe adding something lol

Comment: @ds007, It's ok. You can select the answer if it helped. Thanks